# C# Reading a byte[] and removing rubbish data

Tags: c#, sockets

Couldn't find this on stackoverflow and I did have an example of it which I'd written several months ago, but can't find that either now.

Basically I'm sending byte[] from client to server, displaying it in server window, then planning to act on the data within. The data which I'm receiving, however, is not being cleaned each time, example:

I send "ABCDEF"
Server displays "ABCDEF"
I send "GHI"
Server displays "GHIDEF"

I think you can see where I'm coming from, I just need a method of cleaning the byte[] array, for this side of things.

The next step then would be to only read the bytes which I intend to use, so at the minute although I'm only using X amount of the data, I am actually receiving a LOT more data than I need to, and I need to now dispose of the extra data at the end.

Can anyone advise of how I can go about this?

My codes are below.

Client:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Josh's humble server.");
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2000);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            sock.Bind(ipEnd);
            sock.Listen(100);
            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();
            byte[] mabytes = encoding.GetBytes("Test");
            clientSock.Send(mabytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Hmmm, data sent!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(mabytes));
            Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes("server message");
            while (true)
            {
                clientSock.Receive(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(buffer));
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ex));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Server:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Josh's humble client.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, 2000);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        sock.Connect(ipEnd);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a message:\n");
            byte[] mabyte = encoding.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
            sock.Send(mabyte);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent Data");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you have your client and server codeblocks backwards.  Please edit accordingly to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `clientSock.Receive(buffer);` to get data but never check the return value. It may read smaller then the length of buffer. A more correct way can be:

```
int len = clientSock.Receive(buffer);
Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(buffer,0,len));
```

Also using `byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes("server message");` to allocate bytes is not a good way. 
Use something like `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*N];`

**--EDIT--**

Even this approach can be problematic when a multi-byte char is splitted between consecutive reads.
A better way can be using a TcpClient, wrapping its stream by `new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream())` and read line by line

Comment: To expand on this, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx the return value of Receive is the length that was read.

Comment: Thanks, I've now cleaned the buffer (declared a new buffer for each run of the while statement) and added the length options to getstring, can you tell me what the 0 means though, I know it is byteIndex, does that mean the start of the actual data or something?

Comment: No, Your buffer is filled everytime starting from the `0` index. and encoding will form a string from `byteindex`(which is `0` in your case) using `count` bytes.

Comment: @user1813394 You do not need to clean the buffer.  When you receive the new message it will start at the first byte and in the buffer and run until the buffer is full or the length has been reached.  `len` will then tell you which indexes currently have values.  Cleaning the buffer may result in noticeable performance hit depending on buffer size and the number of messages you are receiving.